# Remove line between two coordinates in a pgfplots line plot

Tags: pgfplots

I can't find a post on this specific topic, although I believe my problem is not unique. If there already is a thread on this which I haven't found, please let me know.

So, I'm trying to make a plot of monetary values using `pgfplots`. However, since the currency changed in the middle of the time series, I want to have a break in the lines, so that the line between 1990 and 2000 is not drawn. How do I remove these single lines?

My example is:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth, xlabel = year,%\,/\,Tsd. Tonnen,
      xmin = 1965, xmax = 2015,
      xtick={1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010},
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      ylabel = example,
      ymin = 1000, ymax = 5000,
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},]
      \addplot 
      coordinates {
(1960,  1650)
(1970,  2550)
(1980,  4050)
(1990,  4550)
(2000,  3550)
(2010,  3750)
         };
       \addplot 
      coordinates {
(1960,  1600)
(1970,  2500)
(1980,  4000)
(1990,  4500)
(2000,  3500)
(2010,  3700)
         };
\legend{a, b}
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{0.4cm} 
\caption[Example.]{Example.}
\end{figure}
```

And the picture looks like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to add `unbounded coords=jump` to the `axis` options, and add a `nan` coordinate somewhere between 1990 and 2000. Below I added `(1995, nan)`, for example.

Alternatively you could split the timeseries over two `\addplot`s, but that adds more work with making sure the plot styles are the same.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth, xlabel = year,%\,/\,Tsd. Tonnen,
      xmin = 1965, xmax = 2015,
      xtick={1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010},
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      ylabel = example,
      ymin = 1000, ymax = 5000,
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      unbounded coords=jump  %%%% added
      ]
      \addplot 
      coordinates {
(1960,  1650)
(1970,  2550)
(1980,  4050)
(1990,  4550)
(1995, nan)
(2000,  3550)
(2010,  3750)
         };
       \addplot 
      coordinates {
(1960,  1600)
(1970,  2500)
(1980,  4000)
(1990,  4500)
(1995, nan)
(2000,  3500)
(2010,  3700)
         };
\legend{a, b}
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That's not even difficult!

Comment: @Newbeee It doesn't always have to be a complicated answer to questions. (You might consider accepting and/or upvoting though, accepting an answer marks the question as solved.)

Comment: @Newbeee I would recommend asking a new question about that problem. I don't know if there is any easier way of doing that than plotting the same data three times: one with just the lines and with just markers, but using different subsets of the data for the two plots with just markers.