# How to change single markers color or form

Tags: pgfplots, color

it's me again :)

I'm trying to make a plot using `pgfplots`. However, I need single markers to look different from the rest, e.g. in the example below I want the marker from 'a' for 1970 and the one from 'b' for 1990 to be an x, and all the rest to be balls (*). (I would be equally happy if you'd tell me a way to distinguish them by color - I hope you understand what I mean.) How do I change these single markers? If there already is a thread on this which I haven't found, please let me know.

My example is:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth, xlabel = year,%\,/\,Tsd. Tonnen,
      xmin = 1965, xmax = 2015,
      xtick={1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010},
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      ylabel = example,
      ymin = 1000, ymax = 5000,
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},]
      \addplot 
      coordinates {
(1960,  1650)
(1970,  2550)
(1980,  4050)
(1990,  4550)
(2000,  3550)
(2010,  3750)
         };
       \addplot 
      coordinates {
(1960,  1600)
(1970,  2500)
(1980,  4000)
(1990,  4500)
(2000,  3500)
(2010,  3700)
         };
\legend{a, b}
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{0.4cm} 
\caption[Example.]{Example.}
\end{figure}
```

And the picture looks like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I thought you want to combine the two features from your [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339711) and this one I used that as a start.

To accomplish what you want to achieve you can make use of the `scatter/classes` feature. On how it works, please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % I assume you *never* want to use the `1000 sep',
        % so remove it *everywhere* with this one call
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=1965,
            xmax=2015,
            xlabel=year,
            xtick={1960,1970,...,2010},
            ymin=1000,
            ymax=5000,
            ylabel=example,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % make use of the "scatter" feature and say that the "classes" are
            % given explicitly in symbolic notation
            scatter,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
            % define as many classes as you need and provide the style to each class
            % (so the "non-default" classes can be either noticed, I changed
            %  also changed the marker size)
            scatter/classes={
                a={},       % empty argument means: use the default style
                b={mark=triangle*,orange,mark size=5pt},
                c={mark=x,green,mark size=5pt}
            },
        ]
            % I changed your coordinates to a table, because than the scatter
            % classes are to add much easier
            %
            % Also I just used an empty line to "break" the connecting line
            % (instead of adding a dummy coordinate with a `NaN' value)
            \addplot table [x=year,y=value,meta=label] {
                year    value   label
                1960    1650    a
                1970    2550    b
                1980    4050    a
                1990    4550    a

                2000    3550    a
                2010    3750    a
             };
            \addplot table [x=year,y=value,meta=label] {
                year    value   label
                1960    1600    a
                1970    2500    a
                1980    4000    a
                1990    4500    c

                2000    3500    a
                2010    3700    a
             };

            % we have to adjust the legend, because in `scatter/classes' this
            % works a bit different
            \legend{
                A,  % class "a" of first `\addplot'
                ,   % class "b" of first `\addplot'     <-- you don't want to show
                ,   % class "c" of first `\addplot'     <-- you don't want to show
                B,  % class "a" of second `\addplot'
%                ,   % ...
%                ,   % ...
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea why it works just fine in a simple figure, but doesn't want to be a subfigure? When I try to make a figure with two panels, it says "can't read table file"...

Comment: Sorry, but with this little information I don't know where the problem could be. Because of that I suggest that you ask a follow-up question where you -- besides the MWE -- state the error message from the LOG file. Would that be ok for you?